# trigger a enter key when a text is clicked inside list jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to trigger an enter key when ever a text is clicked inside `li`. How can I do that?

```
<input type="text" class="copy"/>
<ul>
  <li class="paste">Click-Me</li>
</ul>

<script>
  $(document).on('click', '.copy', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.paste').val($(this).text());
    //press a enter key on the class `paste`
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Faking key presses isn't very reliable. It would be better to execute the logic you're expecting the key event to cause directly. What do you want the enter key to do here?

Comment: li tag don't have value attribute you need to use text()  and input value should be get from $(this).val()

Comment: why do you want to click enter key? Call a function instead